# Difference between deliver and deliver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the difference between "deliver" and "deliver!" methods of the mailer? (specifically for rails 3.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An ActionMailer method can be triggered using one of two methods:
>   either deliver or deliver! - the main difference between the two is
>   that the second will throw exceptions if it cannot be sent, which is
>   why I tend to prefer using it. Something to keep in mind though, is
>   that using deliver! will call any registered Mail Observers, but not
>   Interceptors - meaning that your mail will be sent unaltered.

Taken from this [blog](http://blog.joshmcarthur.com/2011/10/06/action-mailer-interceptors/).